# Embedded PHP in HTML slow loading page

Tags: php, html, twitter

I've a php script that gets tweets and echo them. The problem is the page takes some time to load.

Is there a way I could first load the page as it is, and when the tweets are ready, edit the page with the tweets?

Comment: It might also be a good idea to cache the tweets so they only have to be retrieved every x minutes.

Comment: optimize your SQL query?

Comment: @techouse - Where is SQL mentioned?

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you cached your Tweets in some database :)

Comment: @techouse may actually be on to a good idea there..! ;)

Comment: That's how I wrestled with Twitter. Since set these immoral limitations to their API I simply used a cronjob to call all the user Tweets using a few hundred proxies. I stored that into my database and updated it via the cron once a day. Problem solved :)

Answer (score 1):

document.readyState property can be used to check if your page is loaded.

```
if(document.readyState === "complete") {
  //Already loaded!
}
else {
      //Add onload or DOMContentLoaded event listeners here: for example,
      window.addEventListener("onload", function () {

          /*   you may use ajax to get the tweet contents like this. */
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
              {
              if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
              }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","tweetsPage.php",true);
            xmlhttp.send();

    }, false);

}
```

Comment: How does this help? The page load timing is too slow; and if its due to PHP then it's prior to the mark-up being sent to the browser. No amount of client-side scripting will solve this.

Comment: His twitter tweet code is in php. he can write that ina  different page. The onload eventlistener checks when the dom is loaded. after it is loaded it triggers the listener which goes to the php page to get the tweets. If the page load timing is slow, the onload event will be triggered only after the page loads.

Comment: Perhaps you should've explained that though - instead you just posted a code snippet with an onload event listener and *'document.readyState can check if the page is loaded'*. To me that doesn't seem helpful or even relevant.

Comment: i have written my comments explaining everything. i have not writeen the ajax request code. but i think he can easily get with google search. i helped with the term "Ajax" !! And explained where to use it in the code.

Comment: But this is really not something to argue. You told your views. I accept that.

Comment: Dude, I wasn't arguing. I just simply told you to expand a little to make it clear. Someone has obviously marked you down for the same reason - **but I decided not too**, I thought I'd have the decency to give you a heads-up to help you out.

Comment: Alright. I agree to what you say. I will add few more points.

Comment: heh, Ok then. As I say man - Sorry if you thought I was being a dick. ;) I agree with your approach though!

Comment: No offence. I had no intentions to use shortcuts. But then i too felt, one of the main part was missing and its not too much of code. *Shakes Hand* :)

Answer (score 0):

Try Chirp.js, that's a really good library for loading Tweets with Javascript: http://lab.rog.ie/chirp/

Answer (score 0):

I would go with AJAX, but an alternative would be to create an iframe which uses your twitter code and mark up file as its source

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like PHP isn't really required. I'd go for a a javascript option like Chirp.js; as mentioned above.

However, if you're dead set on using PHP (perhaps you have additional functionality built in to the script?) I would go for the jQuery/AJAX route.

- Have a placeholder div - set the CSS to ensure that it wont break the layout, and have a loading image or similar.
- Run a $.AJAX() request to the PHP script, and then directly output the results of the request into the placeholder div

This should minimise any layout issues whilst still providing a consistent user experience whilst the script is loading. As $.AJAX() is asynch - no functionality on the page will be blocked, as opposed to the current issue where the page isn't even displaying! Naturally, the only downside is that the tweets will still take time to load.

Perhaps if you posted up your PHP script or told us about your server set-up we may be able to troubleshoot the real issue though - **why the PHP script is taking so long to execute?** This is probably the most interesting part of the problem, as you may be doing something incorrectly which could lead to problems later on in production.